# LVM root 100% usage

Tags: server, partitioning, disk-usage, lvm

I've been going round in circles trying to find a fix to this issue, without having to use liveCD and shutting down the server (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS). I can no longer update Ubuntu due to a lack of space on the root partition. For some reason on install, 3 years ago, the boot partition was set at 500MB on a 500GB drive, which apart from that partition is empty. But `df -h` gives...

```
df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        799M   94M  705M  12% /run
/dev/mapper/SERVER--vg-root  450G  428G     0 100% /
tmpfs                        3.9G  208K  3.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1                    472M  117M  332M  26% /boot
tmpfs                        799M   52K  799M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Indicating that the root drive is full. Size of folders in root are...

```
du -h --max-depth=1 -x /
18M     /sbin
743M    /home
12K     /mnt
620K    /samba
4.0K    /lib64
20K     /media
4.0K    /srv
8.0K    /snap
112K    /tmp
713M    /lib
16M     /bin
16K     /lost+found
6.3G    /usr
4.0K    /opt
64K     /repository
456K    /root
16M     /etc
873M    /var
8.6G    /
```

[image: Gparted sdb]

I'm not sure what's taking up all of the space on the sdb5 partition, could be the swap file but `lvs` gives...

```
sudo lvs
  LV     VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Syn                                  c Convert
  root   SERVER-vg -wi-ao---- 457.28g                                                                             
  swap_1 SERVER-vg -wi-ao----   8.00g
```

Indicating that the swap file is only 8GB. Any help with the best way to tackle this issue would be much appreciated.

```
$ lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                     2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                     8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sda1                  8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/MB
sdb                     8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1                  8:17   0   487M  0 part /boot
└─sdb5                  8:21   0 465.3G  0 part
  ├─SERVER--vg-root   252:0    0 457.3G  0 lvm  /
  └─SERVER--vg-swap_1 252:1    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdc                     8:32   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─sdc1                  8:33   0 931.5G  0 part /mnt/ADMIN
sdd                     8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
└─sdd1                  8:49   0   1.8T  0 part /mnt/BACKUP I
sr0                    11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

```
 sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20
du: cannot access './proc/21524/task/21524/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/21524/task/21524/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/21524/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './proc/21524/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access './run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
2751763M        .
2742812M        ./mnt
6363M   ./usr
873M    ./var
743M    ./home
713M    ./lib
114M    ./boot
96M     ./run
18M     ./sbin
16M     ./etc
16M     ./bin
1M      ./tmp
1M      ./srv
1M      ./snap
1M      ./samba
1M      ./root
1M      ./repository
1M      ./opt
1M      ./media
1M      ./lost+found
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! The space on sdb5 is most likely fully taken by the LVM physical volume, you can see it by running `lsblk`. Can your `du` call access all the files (i.e. doesn’t it print any errors)? Consider running it with `sudo` for the root directory.

Comment: To help find where the space is used, try `cd /` and then `sudo du -aBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20` - this command will take  a short while to run the first time, as it scans the directory tree, but you can then descend into the larger directories to see where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks Charles. Added that output above as well as it came up with a few du errors which may be of relevance to the problem?

Comment: The errors are not really relevant: you need to delete some files in /mnt manually: you've just run out of disk space... @Neabhan

Comment: Thanks Fabby, but all the /mnt sub-directories located on different hard drives to root, so how would that help?

Comment: @Neabhan Two things:  1st, preface my name with '@' so that the system flags me if you want to answer me!

Comment: @Neabhan second thing:  If you plug in a drive and use /mnt normally say for backup?  But for some reason one day, your drive is not plugged in while backup is running, then **the files get written to subdirectories under /mnt** - when the drive is plugged in, those directories are masked and you cannot see them.

Comment: @Neabhan Final thing:  Modify the command to `sudo du -xaBM -d 1 . | sort -nr | head -20`  (added -x option) and it should not cross filesystem boundaries.

Comment: @Charles, ahh didn't know about the @, first post here. Thanks for the back-up info, didn't know that could happen, will look into that.

Comment: @Neabhan I only knew about it because my system stopped running one day....

Comment: @Melebius Thanks, have pasted the lsblk output above. du seems to access all files